# Notepad++: How to search for [not "0"]

Tags: notepad++

I have a document like this:

```
Members: 0
Members: 0
Members: 7
Members: 0
Members: 1
Members: 0
Members: 56
Members: 0
Members: 0
Members: 852
Members: 0
```

How can I find all lines where "Members: [x]" with [x] not zero?
File is very large and there are only a few match lines. "Go to next" or similar would be enough, there's no need for fancy code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set search mode "regular expression" in the search dialog, then use the following regular expression:

```
Members: [^0]
```

Comment: Set search mode "regular expression" in the search dialog, then use the regular expression noted above.

Comment: @DwB, Incorporated. (I've never used Notepad++)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!

Comment: What would be the regular expression for pattern like "Some test string Member : 0 some other test string". Where I want to return strings which have Member value as not 0